# How can I use Lion's "look up" feature without the trackpad?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, look-up

Lion introduced the new "Double-tap with three fingers" to **Look up**, which pops up a small definition of whatever word you double-tap. Is there any way to invoke look up without the trackpad? For example, if I'm on a desktop Mac (with a normal mouse) is there any way to quickly look up a word by using this same look up feature?

Comment: @jaberg: The only problem I have with that title is that I specifically want to use the "Look up" feature of Lion, rather than the "Look Up in Dictionary" service which was available in many versions of OS X.

Comment: You're always free to roll back an edit.  FWIW, the keyboard shortcut worked pre-Lion and this feature is a new look applied to an old friend.  Cheers!

Comment: @jaberg: I still see the old feature available in Lion though, which is what could make it confusing. I agree that the original title looked awkward, I just can't think of a good way to phrase it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/three-finger-tap-dictionary-wikipedia-lion.php):

> For years, Mac OS X has had a great shortcut for getting a quick definition of a word: Simply hover the cursor over the word, and press the keyboard shortcut Command-Control-D to bring up a little Dictionary popup. This still works in Lion, but it’s now much more fully featured and also has a great new way to access it.

Your looking for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

<sub>PS: Thanks for asking, it actually made me look and learn something new</sub>

Comment: +1. Does not work in all apps, though (e.g. not in Firefox).

Comment: It works in all Apps that use the system text APIs. Firefox apparently doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking…

[image]